# Preserve IIS web site settings after upgrade

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.7

I have a product and part of it is web site (hosted on IIS). By default during installation I only allow Windows authentication. Sometimes customers enabling basic authentication manually if they need and which is ok.

After upgrading the product, the upgrade process wipes this manual configuration and customer needs to re-enable basic authentication. Is there any way to preserve IIS web site settings during upgrade?

Comment: Two things to look at:

Answer (score 1):

Preserving settings on a major upgrade requires a late scheduled RemoveExistingProducts, eg: after InstallExecute?  We did a lot of work in Wix 3.5 to try to make the IIS 7 custom actions work better with repair & upgrade.

Comment: The preservation depends on using the same component guids so that the REP at the end results in the shared component behavior preserving the site settings, hence the REP at the end answer, correct? Just trying to clarify. If it was based only on custom actions the answer might involve using "and not UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE" in the older install so that no CA runs to remove the settings.

Comment: The IIS CAs depend on component action when determining what operation to perform.  A late schedule REP ensures that components shared between new and old never get a remove action over the course of the upgrade.  NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE would be a pretty bad bug since it would mean that you'd leak state that was removed between the products, not install any new state in the upgrading product, and fail to repair any problems with the existing site.